# Can I charge 2006 or 2007 MacBook with a charger for iPad or iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ipad, macbook-pro, charging, charger

Can I charge 2006 or 2007 MacBook with a charger for iPad or iPhone 5?
Sounds little bit crazy but wouldn't be great if you could use one charger for any Apple device? ;o))))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The iDevice charger has a very limited power output that would be insufficent for running the macbook, let alone charging it.
Going the other way around, however, is a little more doable, an adaptor could be made, but at that point you may as well just plug your iDevice into your macbook's usb port and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice but technically not very feasible.

While all the devices have same Voltage (5 Volt) the problem is in Current requirement.

To make the story short,

The charger can not be to big (since the receiver will only take as much as it needs).

However if the Charger is to small (iphone), it will run very hot since the receiver (Mac) will draw as much as it needs and gets. Since it will not get enough the Mac would not work properly.

Either the charge will die soon, or it will take ages to charge.